# Applicative instance for free monad

Tags: haskell, applicative, free-monad

While trying to find a haskell monad that can be executed stepwise / allows threading, I discovered the free monad

```
data Free f a = Return a | Roll (f (Free f a))
```

with its monad instance

```
instance (Functor f) => Monad (Free f) where
  return = Return
  Return x    >>= f = f x
  Roll action >>= f = Roll $ fmap (>>= f) action
```

and its functor instance

```
instance (Functor f) => Functor (Free f) where
  fmap f (Return x) = Return (f x)
  fmap f (Roll   x) = Roll $ fmap (fmap f) x
```

I know that every monad is an applicative functor with `pure = return` and `(<*>) = ap`.
For me, applicative functors are conceptually harder than monads. For a better understanding of applicative functors, I like to have the applicative instance without resorting to `ap`.

The first line for `<*>`is easy:

```
instance (Applicative f) => Applicative (Free f) where
  pure = Return
  Return f <*> x = fmap f x -- follows immediately from pure f <*> x = f <$> x
--Roll   f <*> x = Roll $ (fmap ((fmap f) <*>)) x -- wrong, does not type-check
```

How to define `Roll f <*> x` in basic terms with `fmap` and `<*>`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Will this do?

```
instance (Functor f) => Applicative (Free f) where
  pure = Return
  Return f  <*> as  = fmap f as
  Roll faf  <*> as  = Roll (fmap (<*> as) faf)
```

The plan is to act only at the leaves of the tree which produces the function, so for `Return`, we
act by applying the function to all the argument values produced by the argument action. For `Roll`, we just do to all the sub-actions what we intend to do to the overall action.

Crucially, what we do when we reach `Return` is already set before we start. We don't change our plans depending on where we are in the tree. That's the hallmark of being `Applicative`: the structure of the computation is fixed, so that values depend on values but actions don't.